# I am not able to get a proper response through browser, but through command line php works perfectly

Tags: php, json, curl, oauth-2.0

Now running through Command Line, I get expected JSON response and successful authentication. 
But through a browser, I get errors. **edit I am able to authenticate and get the code. If I put in the code in instead of the variable, I am able to get a response from the command line.**

Also have tested and am able to sub vars out for the actual strings and still authenticate through command line but not browser.

```
function tokenRequest($clientId, $clientSecret, $code){

$url =  'https://www.strava.com/oauth/token?';
$oauthFields = array(
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'code' => $code);

$parameters = '&' . http_build_query($oauthFields);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($oauthFieldsObject));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
$urlResponse = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
return (json_decode($urlResponse));
}
```

Expected is a json response, but on my main page I decode it but nothing is showing up. Below is the code to try to show the json data.

```
$token = tokenRequest($client_id, $client_secret, $codeUrl);
echo $token;
var_dump($token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, I've added:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
```

Since it was an https site.

Answer (score 0):

1. you must look which oauth version they use
2. your function isnt enough you must request an requestToken then an accessToken and then you must request the user data to get a working

look here: http://strava.github.io/api/v3/oauth/

Comment: I am able to get json data through command line, please see edit above. I have poured over their API oauth page. (have it memorized)

Comment: ok then check pls with $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); the http status code

Comment: adding that returns response: 0

Comment: sry use this http://pastebin.com/r0JEAsD8 i hate an type with this function i get this back object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["message"]=> string(19) "Authorization Error" ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["resource"]=> string(11) "Application" ["field"]=> string(0) "" ["code"]=> string(7) "invalid" } } }

Comment: Yes, its going to fail without the required data since I am trying to authorize. If those values are filled in, I get 'code'object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["access_token"]=>
  string(40) "**********************"
  ["athlete"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (25) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(165762)
    ["resource_state"]=>
    int(3)
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(3) "***"
    ["lastname"]=>

Comment: If I put in the actual code instead of $code then it authorizes through command line, but I still get http response  through the browser '0'